# DX11 CreateDepthStencil View - nullptr

Tags: c++, buffer, directx-11

I am currently working on a school project using DirectX11 and have started making the back buffer here. I believe I have followed everything correctly but, when creating my `DepthStencilView`, I am getting `Null` as return; I'm probably doing somthing stupid but I cant seem to work it out.

Here are all the relevant code snippets.

```
//Depth and Stencil Buffer

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthStencilDesc;

depthStencilDesc.Width = _WindowWidth;
depthStencilDesc.Height = _WindowHeight;
depthStencilDesc.MipLevels = 1;
depthStencilDesc.ArraySize = 1;
depthStencilDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
depthStencilDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
depthStencilDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
depthStencilDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
depthStencilDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

_pd3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilDesc, nullptr, &_depthStencilBuffer);
_pd3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(_depthStencilBuffer, nullptr, &_depthStencilView);

_pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &_pRenderTargetView, _depthStencilView);
```

In my cleanup function:

```
if (_depthStencilView)_depthStencilView->Release();
if (_depthStencilBuffer) _depthStencilBuffer->Release();
```

In my draw function:

```
//Clear depth/stencil
_pImmediateContext->ClearDepthStencilView(_depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);
```

Comment: Which variable ends up being null exactly? The code you posted works for me, it creates _depthStencilView successfully. I hardcoded _WindowWidth and _WindowHeight to 16 since I don't know the size of your window (could your window width/height variables be uninitialized?). By the way, you're not checking return codes of your D3D11 calls. Doing that would make it much easier to debug what's going on. You might also want to pass D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag when creating the D3D device as that will tell you exactly what you're doing wrong when the function calls fail.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to fit it, was just the order moved things around it worked perfectly.